# I am not getting wifi scan results in one plus in background

Tags: android, background, android-wifi, wifimanager, android-background

I am testing my app which has a basic requirement of getting the wifi scan results in background in a service which is running 24/7. 
But it is not working in one plus phones. When the app is in the foreground, it is working fine. But when the app goes to background, it is not giving any scan results.
I am using WifiManager to get the scan results.

Is it a restriction imposed by the Oxygen OS? Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: does it work fine on other phones?

Comment: Not all manufacturers. There is different issue with each manufacturer.